# Ceedling Tests without setUp

Tags: c, unit-testing, ceedling

I am using Ceedling for C unit tests and I want to add a module function to the setUp function. But before I use it, I want to test the function without the setUp function. Is there any way to call a test function without the setUp function.

The workaround for me is to create a second test file for the function and call it separately, but I would like to avoid this.

```
void setUp(void)
{
    module_init();
}

void test_module_init(void)
{
    /* Some test modifications */
    module_init();
    /* Some tests */
}
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't
The solution you suggest (create another test file without setUp) is a good solution